# Overwriting class

Tags: php, class, oop

How can I auto-override classes?

For example, I have 3 files, like `one.php`, `two.php` and `three.php`. In each files I have the same class:

```
class A
{
   function someFunc() {}
}
```

I am having a foreach which loads the 3 files. How can I force PHP to override every time the `A` class? I do not want to have different class names, each has to have the same class name.

I was thinking of namespaces or something like that but I am not that good in namespaces.

Comment: Why do you need to redefine the class? In the case of including other PHP scripts, functions will remain defined if that is the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Each file's classes has different things inside the class, I create each classes into a different variable line `$class_one`, but when I load the the file `two.php` PHP says `Cannot declare class A because the name is already in use`.

Comment: If each file defines a different version of the class, consider naming them differently or inheriting from another generic class.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need all these classes to have the same name. This sounds like an X-Y problem

Comment: Because I am auto-loading a lots of files like this and I am not able to give unique class name for each class. I have a hierarchically structure and that would be so complex when I am at the 17. tree and the class name would look something like `class AdminSettingsAutoCarUserCommentsSettings` and etc. I am identifying the classes by their's file name.

Comment: Oh perfect, then yea, you just need namespaces. This is exactly what they are for. This may be helpful: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: I am trying to solve it by using namespaces in each files but because of this the code wants to lookup for the extend parent class in the same namespace, I fixed it by adding a '\' before the extend parent name like `class A extend \Foo`, but all my classes wants to use the same namespace and it messes up my code. how could I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

This heavily sounds like a code smell.

Why do you need to reuse an existing class name?

I'm almost certain you can solve your problem with interfaces.

Nevertheless here a solution:

A.php:

```
namespace A {
    class Foo { public function __construct() { echo 'A'; } }
}
```

B.php:

```
namespace B {
    class Foo { public function __construct() { echo 'B'; } }
}
```

C.php:

```
namespace C {
    class Foo { public function __construct() { echo 'C'; } }
}
```

loader.php

```
foreach (['A', 'B', 'C'] as $ns) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/'.$ns.'.php';
    $class = $ns.'\\Foo';
    $obj   = new $class();
}
```

Outputs `ABC`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any way to auto-namespace the classes inside the `foreach`? I mean the foreach automatically adds a namespace to it.

Comment: @Bob Of course. But this will add a lot of unnecessary overhead unless you are using some sort of pre-processing.

Comment: Thank you for your code! Is temp file creating would be the only way to do that? I believe creating 17 temp files for each page load would not be that good idea. :/

Answer (score 1):

Just to inform you all, I finally solved it by using namespace. I am going to post here my final solution.

Thank you for everybody for the help!

Each files:

```
namespace Unique\Namespace\Here;

use ExtendParent;

class A extend ExtendParent
{
   ...
}
```